# Store variable created into a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, spyder

I am a finance student, I work on Spyder 3.7 and please find below a piece of my code:

```
def check_ticker():
 import yfinance as yf
 ticker = input("Entrer un ticker ")
 ticker_1 = yf.Ticker(ticker)
 ticker_available_dates = ticker_1.options
 print(ticker_available_dates)
 selected_date = input("Entrer la date choisie ")
 selected_date = str(selected_date)
 ticker_date = ticker_1.option_chain(selected_date)
 ticker_calls = ticker_date.calls
 ticker_puts = ticker_date.puts
 print(ticker_calls.head())
 print(ticker_puts.head())
```

My point is to print the calls and puts values of the ticker I select (from yahoo finance).

My objective is **to store  my variable "ticker_available_dates" in the variable explorer when I use this function**

Do you have any idea ?

Until now, I tried to create first a list (outside of my function) and fill it with a for loop but doesnt work.

Comment: What data specifically do you need outside of the function? `return` that data so the caller can use it.

Comment: Hi, I need "ticker_available_dates" to be a list :)

Comment: return could just print the values but dont store it in the variable explorer

Answer (score 0):

To make it a list in the method:

`ticker_available_dates = list(ticker_1.options)`

You can make a new list outside your method and then append the dates to the list. For example:

```
ticker_dates = list()

def check_ticker():
  ...
  ...
  ticker_available_dates = ticker_1.options

  for i in ticker_available_dates:
     ticker_dates.append(i)
  ...
  ...

check_ticker()

print(ticker_dates)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you a lot for this complete answer, it works :D